# Why would scaleform combine masks on separate movieclips into one?

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, scaleform

I'm working on a project using scaleform gfx 3.3. On a 3Di layer, a bunch of different movieclips are created. Some of them have masks. What appears to happen is that all the masks are combined into a single alpha channel. Each component masks properly when they aren't overlapping, but when they are, they share the mask space of the larger component.

Is there a way to force scaleform to respect their masks individually?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried moving the movie clips to separate layers and retesting? FYI, masking support was greatly improved in Scaleform 4. Is there some reason  you're still on 3.3.?

Comment: I just came across this and it made me smile to remember the hell I was going through with that. I was building the HUD for the alpha version of Star Citizen and they were tied at that point to some old version of cryengine that didn't support Scaleform 4. Glad I got out of that mess. Cheers :)